# Glassfish 3 deploy web module and ejb module independently

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

I have read everywhere in the tutorials of javaee 6 that one can deploy the EJB module and the WEB module on 2 different machines. However I can nowhere find a tutorial on how to archieve this. How do I have to connect the two servers then so that the components in my WEB application can find my remote EJBs ?

Answer (score 0):

Here how I achieved it:
**The EJB**

```
@Stateless(name = "beanname", mappedName = "jndiBeanName")
public class TheBean implements TheBeanRemote {

    @Override
    public String theMethod(String str) {

        return " Bean Invoked " + str;
    }
}
```

**The remote interface for the EJB, muste be in separate JAR so it will be present in the EJB archive and the webapp archive**

```
@Remote
public interface TheBeanRemote {

    public String theMethode(String str);

}
```

**Finally somewhere in your servlet:**

```
    InitialContext ic;
    TheBeanRemote br;
    try {
        String jndiName = TheBeanRemote.class.getName();
        ic=  new InitialContext();
        at =(TheBeanRemote) ic.lookup("jndiBeanName");

        return at.theMethod(parameter); 
  } catch (NamingException ex) {
        //
    }
```

**Note that I packaged the EJB in ear archive.**

Comment: note that works whenr the two modules are deployed on the same server.